# preferred way of synchronous code in async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronous

I've got a simple question, but i think there are multiple answers, but is there a good/bad practise about the following;

i'm working on the implementation for a given interface method:

```
Task<Model> GetDataAsync(CancellationToken token);
```

so in my implementation i get the following signature;

```
public async Task<Model> GetDataAsync(CancellationToken token)
```

however, this implementation lacks any async calls;
just a regular: `return x.firstOrDefault...`

So i get the next problem; and here is some advice needed;
should i do a `await Task.Run(...);` So i can still implement that given interface (that I need btw), or is there a better approach? and what are the benefits.

Comment: I'd return `Task.FromResult(...)`, making it run in another thread doesn't make it async IMO.

Comment: What @orhtej2 said, + remove the async keyword from impl. `await Task.Run` would be only an additional useless context switch

Comment: @orhtej2 technically it would make it asynchronous  but probably overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return completed task from given result without calling for await / Task.Run (considering you really dont want to run it from another thread)

```
public Task<Model> GetDataAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    return Task.FromResult(x.FirstOrDefault(...));
}
```

and dont forget to remove `async` from method signature